# Books/Seforim Similar to Ezra Zion Malamed's "Mefarshei Ha'Mikra"

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books

Does anyone know any books/seforim similar to Ezra Zion Malamed's "Mefarshei Ha'Mikra, which is a book that goes through the methodology of many meforshim and also examples of pasukim and their drash/peshat meanings?

Comment: Same as the second Author of this Dictionary
Practical Talmud Dictionary:

http://www.amazon.com/Practical-Talmud-Dictionary-English-Hebrew/dp/0873065883

Answer (score 1):

Try "[Masters of the Word](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0881259365)", by R' Yonatan Kolatch.